# Using "border-bottom" instead of "text-decoration" for hyperlinks - is it semantically correct?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I see two ways to create underlined links:

1. To use `text-decoration`:

```css
a:link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: 1px underline red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">visit hjkl.org for Vim tricks</a>
```

2. To disable `text-decoration` and use `border-bottom` instead:

```css
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">visit hjkl.org for Vim tricks</a>
```

As you see, the appearance is slightly different.

Is the version that uses `border-bottom` semantically correct? *(This is my question.)*

On the one hand, borders are not really a part of HTML markup, so we cannot say that such **markup** is semantically wrong. The markup is actually the same.

On the other hand, the names of `text-decoration` and `border-bottom` properties are in fact semantic. We don't call them `property-1` and `property-2`.

So, back to my question, is the second version semantically correct or not?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve with the second version? Just curious to understand

Comment: @PsyGik You mean what it the purpose to use `border-bottom` when we already have a more traditional `text-decoration`? Well, there is no real purpose, just self-education and perfectionism. I like how it looks, but I prefer to not use any non-semantic things in HTML.

Comment: Neither is *semantic*, they do different things. Text decoration relates to the text in the element and border relates to the element itself. Semantics has nothing to do with **styling**.

Comment: @Paulie_D This is what I mentioned as "on the one hand". But as you see, I also provided "on the other hand" part.

Comment: and the border bottom has the advanatge that you can style the appearance (dashed, dotted, thickness, different color...). In the end a border property is a valid HTML markup.

Comment: @jsv what other hand? There plenty reasons to use a border-bottom instead of a text-decoration. And like Pauli_D said, semantics have nothing to do with it. it a valid HTML markup in both cases.

Comment: Hands are irrelevant. There is **nothing** semantic about styling. It's not clear what you are after. The properties do different things so your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML semantic has nothing to do with CSS styles. Semantic is concern with using the right tag for the job, and since you are using an anchor element for a link, your code is semantically correct. Now, the rule of thumb when talking about *accessibility* is that each element should be visually differentiated from each other, but using more than just color. As long as you are using another visual cue (apart from color) to differentiate your link from the text around it, you are good to go, and using a border is definitely a good example of that.

Comment: Although you have completely convinced me from technical side, I would say that this question is not completely technical. I mean, we should take into account such thing as consistency. From my point of view, both underline and strike-through are "children" from the same "family". And since we cannot imitate strike-through by using `border`, then using `text-decoration` seems to be a better choice.

Comment: @jsv that has nothing to do with semantics though, which was your question